# Target line for each category in Bar Chart -SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I Need to create a **bar chart** as below in **ssrs** [image]

I struck in creating **target lines** for each category in the **bar chart**. I used strip line option for creating the lines. but its creating only one line. Could any one help me how to create **target lines** for each category in bar chart?

Thanks

Comment: This is just a thought, no testing done.... Take a look at something like a stock or box chart. You could possibly add this as a second series and hide everything except the start value. The data supplied would be your target values. I don;t have time to do any testing but it's worth a look, not sure how you would achieve this otherwise.